# Gray Progress Bar in Macbook Boot caused by Partition Fault

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, efi, partition-recovery

Here's my problem:

When I try to load my Macbook it shows the gray progress bar. It takes a while to fill the whole progress and after it Macbook just shuts down.

I tried to boot from a recovery partition and run Disk Utility to repair it.

Disk Utility showed my "Macintosh HD" in a gray color and failed to repair it. I thought all my data was lost, but then I tried the following:

So I booted into Ubuntu from live USB and it successfully mounted my Macintosh HD HFS+ partition.

Parted shows me the following partitions on my disk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB  210MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      210MB   499GB  499GB  hfs+         Macintosh HD
 3      499GB   500GB  650MB  hfs+         Recovery HD
```

Seems legit except for FAT32 for EFI System Partition.

Since all my data is okay and backed up what should I do to recover the system? I don't really want to reinstall all the system though I believe there's a command to make it allright in Linux.

Comment: fat32 is the correct filesystem for the EFI System Partition. Not sure what you could do to fix it, a reinstall is probably the most effective way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Using that Ubuntu live CD, backup any files you need by mounting the Macintosh HD on there. Your best chance is to simply reinstall OS X. There are no problems with your partition map, it is supposed to be this way.